# Multiple Line Chart in D3 from a csv

Tags: d3.js, linechart

i've a problem with a d3 multi-line chart representation.I want to use [this representation](http://projects.delimited.io/experiments/multi-series/multi-line-full.html). The code is [here](https://github.com/sghall/d3-multi-series-charts/blob/master/multi-line-full.html).

The problem is that my cvs is different by the one of this example. My csv is in this format:

```
 MarketAcq NameMarket -5    -4    -3      -2      -1   0   1   2   3   4   5
 Mining    IronEsc    -0.5% 3.4% 2.1% -4.2% -2.5% 4.4% 6.1% -8.2% 1.4% 2.1% -4.2%
```

Where MarketAcq represents the type of market and nameMarket is the name of the company. -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 is the trend of stock before the acquisition of this company and 1 2 3 4 5 is the trend of stock after the acquisition of this company.

My goal is create a multi line chart from this csv that has on the x axis -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0  1   2   3   4   5 and on y axis the percentage value and in the legend the name of company.

I've a MarketAcq that filter the csv and create the multi line chart only for the company of specified MarketAcq.

The problem is in this part because i don't find a solution for my situation:

```
d3.csv("data/crunchbase-quarters.csv", function (error, data) {  
        var labelVar = 'quarter';  
        var varNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function (key) { return key !== labelVar;});                  
        color.domain(varNames);  
        var seriesData = varNames.map(function (name) {   
          return {  
            name: name,  
            values: data.map(function (d) {  
              return {name: name, label: d[labelVar], value: +d[name]};  
            })  
          };  
        });  
        x.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.quarter; }));  
        y.domain([  
          d3.min(seriesData, function (c) {   
            return d3.min(c.values, function (d) { return d.value; });  
          }),  
          d3.max(seriesData, function (c) {   
            return d3.max(c.values, function (d) { return d.value; });  
          })
        ]);
```

Is there anyone who can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: So your problem is only to read the data from the custom file, not the chart itself?

Comment: Yes i've a problem to read the data from the csv

Answer (score 0):

Since your "csv" data is no real CSV (comma separated) or TSV (tabulator separated) you want to parse the raw string somehow or modify your data formatting to fit any data format, that D3 can parse, e.g.:

```
MarketAcq;NameMarket;-5;-4;-3;-2;-1;0;1;2;3;4;5
Mining;IronEsc;-0.5%;3.4%;2.1%;-4.2%;-2.5%;4.4%;6.1%;-8.2%;1.4%;2.1%;-4.2%
```

If you can't or don't, try something like this:

```
d3.text('data.csv', 'text/plain', function(error, response) {
    var lines = response.split('\n');
    for (var i = lines.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        lines[i] = lines[i].trim().split(/\s+/).join(' ');
    };

    var headers = lines.shift().split(' ');
    var data = new Array(lines.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        data[i] = {};
        var items = lines[i].split(' ');
        for (var x = 0; x < headers.length; x++) {
            data[i][headers[x]] = items[x];
        }
    };

    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i've the csv in this format MarketAcq,NameMarket,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5
Mining,IronEsc,-0.5%,3.4%,2.1%,-4.2%,-2.5%,4.4%,6.1%,-8.2%,1.4%,2.1%,-4.2% the problem is that every example on internet read the file by column i need to read the file by row.The file on internet are similar to this disposition year industry1 industry2